# Building a directory path / and double quote

Tags: c#, asp.net, format, quote

I am trying to build a path to put a file there, but I am using `string.Format` and the `/` doesn't appears between the parameters.
This is my example:

```
    string pdfFile = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", "MyPDF", "/", this.IdPDF, "/");
```

Can someone tell me why the `/` between the `JPG` and `Id` doesn't appear?

Here is the answer thanks Damith and rest of all!

```
string pdfFile = string.Format("{0}/{1}", "MyPDF", this.idPDF);
```

Comment: -1: Please show data that reproduces the issue - it is unclear what "Id" is and what resulting value of "Folder" you see. As it stands now there is nothing wrong with the code (except trying to build path with String.Format instead of `Path.Combine`). Side note: "please" spelled differently (and totally unnecessary in the SO questions), the valid phrase for your spelling is "plz give me teh codez".

Comment: Please post the actual result you are getting, along with the value of `Id` being used.  If I run your code, I get the correct output with the appropriate placement of '/'.

Comment: @user2112420 how is the final path supposed to be?

Comment: I already did, the only variable is the This.IDPDF: I want to get this: /MyPDF/2/   and after that will be my file ex: /MyPDF/2/sales.pdf

Comment: @user2112420 then your code should work perfectly. Do you then get `/MyPDF/2/sales.pdf` instead of `/MyPDF2/sales.pdf`? See my edited answer below.

Comment: `string pdfFile = string.Format("/{0}/{1}/{2}", "MyPDF", this.idPDF, pdfName);`

Comment: What is the value of `This.IDPDF` and **what is the actual output that you get**?

Comment: This.IDPDF is a value like 1, 2, 3..etc, it will be the name of the folder. I want to list in a folder PDF, folder with named ID(1,2..etc) depending of the user(imagine this.IDPDF is the ID of the user, so I will have all the PDF of the users)

Comment: The thing is that I dont get the slash /, if I do other way that I get the / but with another ID, I think is setting the ascii..

Comment: Questions like this make one want to stop contributing to SO

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx):

```
string folder = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"\MyPDF", Id, "sales.pdf");
```

This will generate something like `\MyPDF\2\sales.pdf`. In general, `Path.Combine` will concatenate all parameters to build a path. From the MSDN example:

```
string[] paths = {@"d:\archives", "2001", "media", "images"};
string fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
```

`fullPath` would be `d:\archives\2001\media\images`.

Comment: Id - it's variable, not literal

Comment: The path is in azure, so I have to upload a file to azure under a path, I give that path for the jpg generated dynamically.

Comment: +1 for suggestion of proper function, also there is no visible bug in OP's code so far.

Comment: @user2112420 I don't understand the issue with azure. What is the final path supposed to be?

Comment: The final path has to be /PDF/id/SALES.PDF  sales.pdf is the name of the file that I concat to the path, so my path is only "/pdf/id/"